# What is the difference between XAMPP or WAMP Server & IIS?

Tags: iis, xampp, wamp

I want to know what's the main difference between  XAMPP or WAMP Server & IIS Server?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

WAMP is an acronym for **W**indows (OS), **A**pache (web-server), **M**ySQL (database), **P**HP (language).

XAMPP and WampServer are both free packages of WAMP, with additional applications/tools, put together by different people. There are also other WAMPs such as UniformServer. And there are commercial WAMPs such as WampDeveloper (what I use).

Their differences are in the format/structure of the package, the configurations, and the included management applications.

IIS is a web-server application just like Apache is, except it's made by Microsoft and is Windows only (Apache runs on both Windows and Linux).  IIS is also more geared towards using ASP.NET (vs. PHP) and "SQL Server" (vs. MySQL), though it can use PHP and MySQL too.

Comment: are there also any special difference between the functionality. cause i am facing problem in implementing mailing functionality. if it is working in wamp there are chances it does not work in xampp.
(not bothered about IIS)

Comment: Thanks of this information, very useful

Answer (score 12):

WAMP [ Windows, Apache, Mysql, Php]

XAMPP [X-os, Apache, Mysql, Php , Perl ] (x-os : it can be used on any OS )

Both can be used to easily run and test websites and web applications locally.
WAMP cannot be run  parallel with XAMPP because with default installation  XAMPP gets priority and it takes up ports.

WAMP easy to setup configuration in. 
WAMPServer has a graphical user interface to switch on or off individual component softwares while it is running.
WAMPServer provide an option to switch among many versions of Apache, many versions of PHP and many versions of MySQL all installed which provide more flexibility towards developing while XAMPPServer doesn't have such an option.
If you want to use Perl with WAMP you can  configure Perl with WAMPServer http://phpflow.com/perl/how-to-configure-perl-on-wamp/ but it is better to go with XAMPP.

XAMPP is easy to use than WAMP.
XAMPP is more powerful. 
XAMPP has a control panel from that you can start and stop individual components (such as MySQL,Apache etc.). 
XAMPP is more resource consuming than WAMP because of heavy amount of internal component softwares like Tomcat , FileZilla FTP server, Webalizer, Mercury Mail etc.So if you donot need high features better to go with  WAMP.
XAMPP also has SSL feature which WAMP doesn't.(Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)  is a networking protocol that manages server authentication, client authentication and encrypted communication between servers and clients. )

IIS acronym for Internet Information Server also an extensible web server initiated as a research project for for Microsoft NT.IIS can be used for making  Web applications, search engines, and  Web-based applications that access databases such as SQL Server within Microsoft OSs. . 
IIS  supports HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, FTPS, SMTP and NNTP.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the above, WAMP supports 64 bit PHP on Windows systems while XAMPP only offers 32 bit versions. This actually made me switch to WAMP on my Windows machine since you need 64 bit PHP 7 to get bigint numbers correctly from MySQL

Comment: XAMPP is now supporting PHP 7. The part about bigint numbers are still valid, though

Answer (score 7):

XAMPP is more powerful and resource taking than WAMP.
WAMP provides support for MySQL and PHP.
XAMPP provides support for MYSQL, PHP and PERL

XAMPP also has SSL feature while WAMP doesnt. 
If your applications need to deal with native web apps only, Go for WAMP.
If you need advanced features as stated above, go for XAMPP.

As of priority, you cant run both together with default installation as XAMPP gets a higher priority and it takes up ports. So WAMP cant be run in parallel with XAMPP.

Answer (score 6):

**WAMP** stands for **W**indows,**A**pache,**M**ysql,**P**hp

**XAMPP** stands for **X**-os,**A**pache,**M**ysql,**P**hp,**P**erl.
*(x-os means it can use for any operating system)*

### Advantages of XAMPP:

- It is cross-platform software
- It possesses many other essential modules such as phpMyAdmin, OpenSSL, MediaWiki, WordPress, Joomla and more.
- it is easy to configure and use.

### **Advantages of WAMP:**

- It is easy to Use. (Changing Configuration)
- WAMP is Available for both 64 bit and 32-bit system.

> if you are running projects which have specific version requirements
> WAMP is better choice because you can switch between multiple
> versions. for example 7x and PHP 5x or Magento2.2.4 won't work on
> php7.2 but Magento2.3.needs php7.2 or up to work.

i suggest using **laragon** :

Laragon works out of the box with not only **MySQL/MariaDB** but also **PostgreSQL** & **MongoDB**. With Laragon, they are portable & reliable so you can focus on what matters
Laragon is a portable, isolated, fast & powerful universal development environment for PHP, Node.js, Python, Java, Go, Ruby. It is fast, lightweight, easy-to-use and easy-to-extend.

Laragon is great for building and managing modern web applications. It is focused on performance - designed around stability, simplicity, flexibility and freedom.

Laragon is very lightweight and will stay as lean as possible. The core binary itself is less than 2MB and uses less than 4MB RAM when running.

Laragon doesn’t use Windows services. It has its own service orchestration which manages services asynchronously and non-blocking so you’ll find things run fast & smoothly with Laragon.

### **Advantages of Laragon:**

- **Pretty URLs**
  Use `app.test` instead of `localhost/app`.
- **Portable**
  You can move Laragon folder around (to another disks, to another laptops, sync to Cloud,…) without any worries.
- **Isolated**
  Laragon has an isolated environment with your OS - it will keep your system clean.
- **Easy Operation**

  Unlike others which pre-config for you, Laragon `auto-configsall` the complicated things. That why you can add another versions of PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, Go, Apache, Nginx, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB,… effortlessly.
- **Modern & Powerful**
  Laragon comes with modern architect which is suitable to build modern web apps. You can work with both Apache & Nginx as they are fully-managed.
  Also, Laragon makes things a lot easier:Wanna have a Wordpress CMS? Just 1 click.Wanna show your local project to customers? Just 1 click.Wanna enable/disable a PHP extension? Just 1 click.

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP and WAMP are both web server applications for PHP and MYSQL with the apache server. When we consider IIS, it also a web-server like apache runs on windows only.

XWAMPP/WAMP - **W**indows,**A**pache,**M**ysql,**P**HP

IIS - Apache,SQL Server, ASP.NET

If you like to read more about  [XWAMPP vs WAMP](https://hostfocuz.com/xampp-vs-wamp/)

Answer (score 0):

WAMP: acronym for Windows OS, Apache(Web server), MySQL (Database) and PHP.

XAMPP: acronym for X (any OS), Apache (Web server), MySQL (Database), PHP/PERL.

Answer (score 0):

One of their differences are in the format/structure of the package, the configurations, and the included management applications, In short: XAMPP supports more OSes and includes more features. XAMPP is easy to use than WAMP. XAMPP is more powerful. XAMPP has a control panel from that you can start and stop individual components (such as MySQL,Apache etc.). XAMPP is more resource consuming than WAMP because of heavy amount of internal component software