# iframe refused to connect while using XAMPP and Laravel

Tags: laravel, xampp

I am developing a Laravel application and have added an iframe as follows:

The iframe does not connect and simply says [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) refused to connect.  I have done some research and it appears this related to X-Frame-Options being set.  Within the Chrome Browser Developer Tools, I see the following error message:

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://www.google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

My guess is this is a setting that needs to be changed at the XAMPP server level within Apache but I cannot figure out where.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing on localhost and you have no control of the response headers, you can disable it with a chrome flag.

open this URL :

```
chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies
```

and disable `SameSite by default cookies`

[image]

`SameSite` prevents the browser from sending the cookie along with cross-site requests.

if you don't want to disable `SameSite by default cookies` you can add response header before sending back response to resolve this:

```
return response($content)
              ->header("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I thought for sure this would work, but unfortunately neither worked.  I restarted XAMPP and ran php:artisan serve again.  It's really odd.

Comment: It worked now.  One mistake I made was using www.google.com as the link in the iframe.  Apparently that is blocked

Comment: I suggest using laragon instead of xampp...see this post of mine for more info
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60383405/5753091